# Validation for a 10 digit phone number in dojo ValidationTextBox

Tags: validation, dojo, dijit.form

I'm working with **dojo1.7** and here i'm looking for a simple regex or range/places that will validate a **10 digit phone number** of `dijit.form.ValidationTextBox`.

I'd like to make sure that the number is exactly 10 digits, **no letters, hyphens or parens or other special chars**. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exact 10 digits, you can use the RegExp `\d{10}`. Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Telephone Number Check</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script>
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"]);
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <label for="tel">Enter your 10 digits telephone number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="tel" value=""
    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
    data-dojo-props="regExp:'\\d{10}', required:true, invalidMessage:'Invalid telephone number.'">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="reverveAmount" required="true" style="width:50px" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props='maxLength:"3",constraints:{places:1,min:1,max:20}, regExpGen:function(){ return "\\d+" }, required:true, invalidMessage:"Number only"'>
```

It's work good for me.

Answer (score 0):

To force a format you can override the **filter** method. The default **filter** method comes from **_TextBoxMixin.js**, which is where trim, uppercase, lowercase, and propercase are implemented.

This reformats a **ValidationTextBox** value as ###-###-####.
Just remove the two splice lines if you don't want hyphens. Of course you could implement the filter method in other ways, such as by using **dojo/number**.

```
declare('calpoly/form/FormattingPhoneNumber', [ValidationTextBox], {

    regExp:"\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}",
    invalidMessage:"Please enter a 10-digit phone number",

    filter:function(val){
        val = lang.trim(val);
        var s = [];
        for(var i=0; i<val.length;i++){
            if(!isNaN(val[i])){
                s.push(val[i]);
            }
        }
        if(s.length!=10){
            // Not a 10-digit phone number, return what the user typed, regex will invalidate.
            return val;
        }
        s.splice(3,0,'-');
        s.splice(7,0,'-');
        return s.join('');
    }
});
```